# Selenium Webdriver pass email to form by js

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

How can I pass email into [this form](https://www.wrike.com/price/)?

You need just click "Professional - Start free trial", which is where I need pass email using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the popup for providing your email is in a different frame. You should manage Context switching:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Email extends BrowserFunctions{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.wrike.com/price/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("start-free-trial-professional")));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
    driver.switchTo().frame("ajaxIframeFeatures");
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'abc@gmail.com');", driver.findElement(By.id("email")));
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("start-project")));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
}
```

Sorry for using too much of `Thread.sleep()`, it's not a good practice generally. You can replace it by `WebDriverWait` if you want to improve the performance.

I hope it helps :)